# Is GitLab blocking user when he failed login via LDAP

Tags: ldap, gitlab

We have **GitLab Community Edition 9.1.3** (2e4e522) on our Linux server. We use AD logins because of our corp. policy.

Configuration file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: '{HOST}'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     method: 'plain'
     bind_dn: 'CN=SVCJAVACZ,OU=FUNCTIONAL,OU=Users,OU=CZ,OU=MCC,DC=r3,DC=madm,DC=net'
     password: '{PASSWORD}'
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'DC=r3,DC=madm,DC=net'
     user_filter: ''
     attributes:
       username: ['uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName']
       email:    ['mail', 'email', 'userPrincipalName']
       name:       'cn'
       first_name: 'givenName'
       last_name:  'sn'
 EOS
```

My LDAP login is working correctly. Colleagues I work with are able to login as well without any problems. But few days ago one of the users tried to login to GitLab application using LDAP and was not successful (3 times - always 302). It seems that from that time he gets periodically blocked in our network (even on VPN).

As written in [GitLab LDAP troubleshooting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html#troubleshooting) I opened the `application.log` but it was empty and info from `production.log` to this state is:

```
Started POST "/users/auth/ldapmain/callback" for {IP} at 2017-05-28 15:51:55 +0200
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"{TOKEN}", "username"=>"{USERNAME}", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}
Redirected to {ADDRESS}/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

From file `unicorn_stdout.log`:

```
I, [2017-05-28T15:51:55.388593 #14907]  INFO -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2017-05-28T15:51:55.569159 #14907] ERROR -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials encountered.
```

From command mentioned in [GitLab Maintenance of Tasks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html) `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`:

```
System information
System:         Ubuntu 16.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.3.3p222
Gem Version:    2.6.6
Bundler Version:1.13.7
Rake Version:   10.5.0
Redis Version:  3.2.5
Git Version:    2.11.1
Sidekiq Version:4.2.7

GitLab information
Version:        9.1.3
Revision:       2e4e522
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:            http://{URL}
HTTP Clone URL: http://{URL}/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@{URL}:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP:     yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        5.0.2
Repository storage paths:
- default:      /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

In there in GitLab any cache that would periodically send blocking command for users that have tried to login but failed (and therefore get blocked ever since)?

Or any suggestions in what to look into now? Any ideas?

Comment: As in the documentation states there should also be a log in the file `application.log`. Add this one too to get the whole picture

Comment: @secustor Well the `application.log` for that day was all empty..  But I will state it there ;)